# Adding mask in jqGrid colum on editing line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to create a phone mask for some columns when I add or edit a record using jqGrid (my jqGrid version is 4.5.4).

Below my code:

```
this.montarGRID = function (p_gridName, p_dados, p_header, p_descriptor, p_contentName, p_primaryKey, p_filtroGrid) {
jQuery("#" + p_gridName).jqGrid( {
    data : p_dados, 
    datatype : "local", 
    sortable : true, 
    colNames : p_header, 
    colModel : p_descriptor,
...
```

This grid is generated dynamically. I pass a json with the content of colModel.

```
[
{"formatter":"integer","index":"id","hidden":true,"sortable":true,"sorttype":"integer","width":75,"align":"center","name":"id"},
{"formatter":"telefone","index":"TELCONTATO01","search":true,"hidden":false,"sorttype":"text","sortable":true,"width":0,"align":"right","name":"TELCONTATO01","editoptions":{"text":true,"required":false,"dataInit":"function (elem) {  return mostra_telefone(elem); }"},"editrules":{"text":true,"required":false,"dataInit":"function (elem) {  return mostra_telefone(elem); }"},"editable":true},
{"formatter":"telefone","index":"TELCONTATO02","search":true,"hidden":false,"sorttype":"text","sortable":true,"width":0,"align":"right","name":"TELCONTATO02","editoptions":{"text":true,"required":false,"dataInit":"function (elem) {  return mostra_telefone(elem); }"},"editrules":{"text":true,"required":false,"dataInit":"function (elem) {  return mostra_telefone(elem); }"},"editable":true}
]
```

the method that generates the phone mask ...

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        mostra_telefone : function (elem) {
            $(elem).mask("(99)9999-9999?");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But it is never invoked when I select, change or add the record.

Comment: Let me ask some questions. How look the telephone source data when it is passed to the grid?  How do you want to be displayed in grid?  how do you want to be displayed and checked when it is edited. **Example answer**: The source telephone field  is like this : 12345678. In grid I want to be displayed like "Telephone:12345678", when edited in inline edit I want to be displayed like (12)-345-678 and checked if it is correctly inputed.

Comment: The source telephone field is 2899695910, in grid I watn to be displayed like (28)9969-5910 and when edited in inline edit I want to be displayed like (28)9969-5910, and the user cannot enter letters or more than 10 numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pice of code which do the desired behavior. For this purpose we use inputpask plugin.
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        ...
        colModel :[

```
                {
                    name: 'Telephone',
                    width: 100,
                    formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        var re = new RegExp("([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4,6})", "g");
                        return cellvalue.replace(re, "($1) $2-$3"); 
                    },
                    unformat : function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return cellvalue.replace("(",'').replace(") ",'').replace("-",'');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "custom",
                    editoptions :{
                        custom_element : function(value, options) {
                            var el = document.createElement("input");
                            el.type="text";
                            el.value = value;
                            $(el).addClass('inline-edit-cell ui-widget-content ui-corner-all').inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
                            return el;                              
                        },
                        custom_value : function(elem, operation, value) {
                            if(operation === 'get') {
                                return $(elem).val().replace("(",'').replace(") ",'').replace("-",'').replace(/\_/g,'');;
                            } else if(operation === 'set') {
                                $(elem).val(value);
                            }                               
                        }
                    },
                    editrules : {
                        requiered : true,
                        custom : true,
                        custom_func : function(val, name) {
                            // special replace mask at end
                            var cel  = val.replace("(",'').replace(") ",'').replace("-",'').replace(/\_/g,'');
                            if(cel.length !== 10) {
                                return [false,"Please, enter correct phone number"];
                            } 
                            return [true,""];
                        }
                    }   
                },                  

          ....
       ],
    ....
});
```

This code should work in you version too.
Also here is a [link to the demo](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/formatter_telefone/).

Comment: Tony, I followed the instructions and it worked! Thank you!

But now I need this code to be contained in a JSON because I need to dynamically generate the colModel value. I even managed to pass the formatter as a string and execute a jquery method to format and unformat the mask.

Is it possible to do the same with "custom_value", "custom_func" and "custom_element" methods?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Not all events can be set as strings. If you generate the model automatically via json this mean that you store parameters in database. For this purpose Guriddo jqGrid version 5 and up, has a build in methods for export and import which does not matter how the events are defined (event functions are treated correctly). This is in Guriddo jqGrid - I can't remember if this functionality is available in your version, since it is very old.

Comment: Look [here for more info](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/persiststate/) on Guriddo jqGrid. Please read to the end in order to see the methods available.

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem Tony. I went through the JSON that I generated and changed the string to the "reserved word" that triggers the "custom_value", "custom_func" and "custom_element" methods. I put the solution code in a new answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this:

```
function custom_element_telefone(value, options){
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.type="text";
    el.value = value;
    $(el).addClass('inline-edit-cell ui-widget-content ui-corner-all').inputmask({"mask": "(99)9999-9999#"});
    return el;
};

this.montarGRID = function (p_gridName, p_dados, p_header, p_descriptor, p_contentName, p_primaryKey, p_filtroGrid) {

    p_descriptor.forEach(col => {
        if (!col.editoptions) return;
        if (!col.editoptions.custom_element) return;

        switch (col.editoptions.custom_element) {
            case "custom_element_telefone":
                col.editoptions.custom_element = custom_element_telefone;
                break;            
        }
    });

    jQuery("#" + p_gridName).jqGrid( {
        data : p_dados, 
        datatype : "local", 
        sortable : true, 
        colNames : p_header, 
        colModel : p_descriptor,
...
```